# Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence in a metric space. Show that $\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \lim x_n$ is a compact subset.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Hello I am trying to show the following.

Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence in a metric space. Show that $\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{\lim x_n\}$ is a compact subset.

I am proving by Heinel-Borel, therefore I have to prove that the set is bounded and closed. I have already proved that the set is bounded, can anyone help me out with the close statement?

Comment: What limit point(s) can the set possibly have?

Comment: Also, it seems like your question is about metric spaces in general. In that case, Heine Borel does not apply. Indeed, there are metric spaces where a set may be closed and bounded but not compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, Heine Borel does not apply.

Let $x := \lim x_n$ and $X$ be the set in question. Let $\cal U$ be an open cover of $X$. There exists some $U_0 \in \cal U$ containing $x$.
Since $U_0$ is open, there exists some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $x_n \in U_0$ for all $n > N.$
Thus, $U_0 \setminus X$ has at most $N$ elements. For each element, you can pick open sets $U_1, \ldots, U_N$ from the cover $\cal U$.

Then, $\{U_0, \ldots, U_N\}$ is a desired finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

The Heine-Borel theorem does not hold in metric spaces in general. However, the result is easy to prove directly from the definition of compactness: start with an open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of the set in question, and show that it has a finite subcover. HINT: Some member of $U$ must contain the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> In a metric space $X$, let $x_n$ be a sequence that converges to the element $a$. Then the set $M=\left\{a, x_1, x_2, \ldots\right\}$ is compact.

**Solution 1.**

According to Heine-Borel's theorem, the set.
$$
M=\left\{x_n \in X \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \cup\{a\}
$$
is compact if and only if it is both bounded and closed. Since the sequence is convergent by premise and hence also bounded, $M$ is already bounded.

It remains to show that $M$ is closed, that is, the limit of any convergent sequence in $M$ is also in $M$. Given an arbitrary sequence
$$
(x_n)_n \subseteq M \quad \text{ with }\quad \lim_n x_n=b, \quad b\in X.
$$
We now consider that $b \in M$ holds. For the sake of clarity, we distinguish the following two cases:

**(a)** The sequence is constant $a$ starting at index $N$, so.
$$
\exists\, N\in \mathbb{N}: y_n=a \quad \forall \, n \geq N.
 $$
Thus the sequence $\left(y_n\right)_n$ converges to $a$ and because of the uniqueness of the limit we get $b=a$ and thus as desired $b \in M$.

**(b)** For infinitely many indices $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $y_n \neq a$ holds. Thus, if we proceed to an appropriate subsequence $(y_{n_j})_j$ of $\left(y_n\right)_n$, we can even use $y_{n_j} \neq a$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Because of $(y_{n_j})_j \subseteq M \backslash\{a\}$ holds.
$$
\forall \,j \in \mathbb{N} \quad \exists \, k_j \in \mathbb{N}: y_{n_j}=x_{k_j}.
 $$
By moving, if necessary, to a growing subsequence of $\left(k_j\right)_j \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we see directly that the sequence $(x_{k_j})_j$ is a subsequence of $(y_n)_n$. But this converges to $a$ by precondition, so in particular $(y_{n_j})_j$ and $(y_n)_n$ also have this limit. So in this case it follows again $b \in M$.

Thus, as desired, we have shown that the set $M$ is compact.

---

**Solution 2.**

We consider that the set $M$ is cover compact (compact). Let $(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \lambda}$ be an open covering of $M$, that is, every set $O_\lambda \subseteq X$ is open and, moreover, it holds that
$$
    M \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in \lambda} O_\lambda.
\tag{1}
$$
To prove that $M$ is cover compact, we need to show that $M$ can only be covered by finitely many of the open sets (finite partial cover). First, because of (1), there is an index $\lambda_0 \in \lambda$ with $a \in O_{\lambda_0}$. Thus $a$ is an interior point of the open set $O_{\lambda_0}$, which is why we find a number $\varepsilon>0$ with $B_{\varepsilon}(a) \subseteq O_{\lambda_0}$. As usual, here $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ denotes the open ball around $a$ with radius $\varepsilon$.

Since the sequence $\left(x_n\right)_n$ converges to $a$ by premise there is by definition a natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ which depends on $\varepsilon$, with
$$
d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon \quad \text{ or equivalently } \quad x_n \in B_{\varepsilon}(a) \quad \forall\, n \geq N.
$$
But this means just $x_n \in O_{\lambda_0}$ for all $n \geq N$. Thus, except for finitely many sequence members, all members lie in the open set $O_{\lambda_0}$. Finally, because of (1), for every $j \in\{1, \ldots, N-1\}$ we find an index $\lambda_j \in \Lambda$ and an open set $O_{\lambda_j}$ with $a_j \in O_{\lambda_j}$.
Let us now write
$$
M=\{x_1, \ldots, x_{N-1}\} \cup\{x_n \in X \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \text { with } n \geq N\} \cup\{a\},
$$
so with our considerations it follows as desired
$$
M \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{N-1} O_{\lambda_j} \cup O_{\lambda_0},
$$
that is, we have found a finite partial cover of the set $M$.

Thus, as desired, we have shown that the set $M$ is compact.

---

**Solution 3.**

In this part we will prove that the set $M$ is sequence compact (compact). To do this, we need to show that every sequence from $M$ has a convergent subsequence. To this end, let $(y_n)_n \subseteq M$ be any sequence. We distinguish the following two cases:

**(a)** The sequence takes a value in $M$ any number of times. Thus the sequence $(y_n)_n$ automatically has a constant subsequence which is obviously convergent.

**(b)** The sequence takes any value from $M$ only finitely often. Let us define for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the set
$$
M_k=\left\{x_j \in X \mid j \in\{1, \ldots, k\}\right\},
$$
then for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists at least one index
$$
N_k \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \notin M_{N_k}\quad \forall\, n \geq N_k.
$$
Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since the sequence $ (y_n )_n$ converges to $a$ by precondition,
$$
\exists\, K \in \mathbb{N}: d(y_n-a)<\varepsilon\quad \forall\,n \geq K.
$$
Thus, for $n \geq N_K$ it follows.
$$
d(y_n-a)=d(x_n-a)<\varepsilon,
$$
that is, the subsequence $(y_n)_n$ also converges to $a$.

Thus, as desired, we have shown that the set $M$ is compact.